# Is there an alternative notation for polychords that won't be confused with slash notation?

Tags: notation, chords, harmony

We have a [terrific guide](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/104163/21766) on slash notation, a notational practice in which, for example, Gm/D means a G-minor triad with a D in the bass (i.e., in second inversion). A polychord, though, is indicated by a *horizontal* slash (as opposed to the vertical slash of slash notation) to show a G-minor triad above a D-major triad.

But this distinction is tricky to typeset clearly, and [sometimes it's downright unclear](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/105323/21766) if the slash is vertical or horizontal.

Are there alternative methods for indicating polychords, especially in typed environments where the horizontal slash can be tricky to input?

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not aware of an alternate which is too bad because like you say typesetting a fraction is tricky at best. The shame is that a regular slash would work for all polychords with the exception of those that have a major triad on the bottom: A/C7 Cmaj7/Dm Bb/Gm are all understandable but G/C is just a bass note below instead of a triad. Maybe an alternate way to name a triad is the solution, C(tr) or Cmaj or C35. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy The Cmaj or CM idea does seem most straightforward, since those are already in use for triads.

Comment: @Aaron I like CM since Cm is minor. Who do we speak to about implementing this?

Comment: Using John's idea, but a backwards rather than forwards slash would nail it. But it wouldn't be known world-wide. Although it would be pretty well self-explanatory - as in *this isn't a bog-standard slash chord*.  A\C7, C\Dm for examples. Gotta start somewhere!

Comment: Something that might prove helpful here is the convention to use capital letters for chord symbols and minuscles for single note. So Gm over a D in the bass could be notated Gm/d, while Gm over a D major triad would be Gm/D.

Comment: I've only ever seen polychords notated with a perfectly horizontal line between the chords. I don't find it hard or ambiguous to separate between that and slash notation 

https://musictheory.pugetsound.edu/mt21c/images/unit12/polychord-rite-chord.svg

Comment: You could try employing roman numerals partially to distinguish polychords from inversion notation. But that's functional-harmonic notation, which may or may not suit your case.

Comment: Some other ideas: As long as you're not using "+" to indicate raised (sharp) chord tones, you could have **Gm+D**.  Or, you could borrow the "union" symbol from set theory and use **Gm∪D**.

Comment: What do you mean with typed environments? Are you using an old typewriter or do you have access to unicode or markup? (Side note, I think ampersand & is more common to find on keyboard than the union symbol and pretty close in meaning, or maybe | if you think of logical or)

Comment: @Emil as long as we don't get too hung up on the strict mathematical meanings,  the **&** is probably a better option than **|** because it's more distinct from **/**.

Comment: Is it important, which program we talk about?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to encapsulate the chord with brakets.  [G/B] .  I personally use standard notation sheet music instead of slash notation.  I've never ran into a situation where the player was still learning how to strum.  Mostly because an arpeggio sounds better than a strum.  And strums are indistinguishable to the audience unless it's supported by the drums.

Comment: With "[G/B]" written, I'd play an inversion, not polychord. Unusual notations have to be explicitly described, something like "[G/B] means a polychord with G and B".

Comment: O.I.C.  so Maybe something like GpB. Or G chord / B chord. No easy standard that I know of exists. Thank God for written music.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the notation programs do offer options for slash/bass notation that are confusingly close to   the polychord 'fraction'. It behoves the engraver to choose styles that AREN'T ambiguous.  Sibelius, for one, makes a distinction that is perfectly  clear, and easy to achieve.

You could concoct your own notation for scores where slash chords are mixed with polychords, perhaps put a box around the polychords?  As I've done (unnecessarily) in the example below.

But this WOULD be your own private system, and would require explanation.   As far as I know there's no generally understood convention other than slash or fraction.

[image]

Comment: The whole polychord concept is so rarely used, it requires explanation, regardless of how it's notated, IMO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here ([jazzpianosite](https://www.thejazzpianosite.com/jazz-piano-lessons/jazz-chords/polychords/)) are a few approaches, perceiving or interpreting the polychord as an extended chord and/or change of scale:

[image: example]

[garciamusic.com](https://garciamusic.com/educator/articles/clear.chord.symbols.html) shows a few more alternative notations, following the same idea, for some more complex situations, still conveying, how the chord is built:

[image]