# What is the function of this slash chord in a Swedish Traditional song?

Tags: chord-theory

In the score

"Du großer Gott, wenn ich die Welt betrachte" (Traditional song from Sweden, Arrangement by Jürgen Glenk, Kreative Klavierbegleitung, p. 113)

I found the following chord progression

[image]

I do not entirely understand what the E/A slash chord is for and its functional use. Is this a dominant chord with an added bass note or is it a ninth chord with omitted third in the tonic? If the former, why is not an e used in the bass? Is it for keeping the bass line smoother?

Could the chord even be understood as a triple appoggiatura?

Comment: You might find an answer in [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104163/what-does-the-chord-notation-x-y-slash-chord-mean/104164#104164) or in some of the links therein.

Comment: Where does this passage occur in the piece?

Comment: And can you post more of the context, showing what happened just before this excerpt? I strongly suspect we've just modulated from D major.

Comment: Michael, first verse, near the beginning.

Comment: Andy, nothing special really happens before - the intro is very similar, it all goes like this

Answer (score 8):

The bass `A` is a *[pedal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_point)*.

If we go by the key signature, it is a *tonic* pedal.

This progression reminds me of something similar, but in classical style...

[image]

As you can see it also uses a dominant chord `E7` in the treble over a tonic `A` in the bass.

This classical progression is used to affirm a tonic, and it might be used at either the beginning of a piece to establish a tonic, or after a modulation to extend the new key for a bit. The tonic affirming aspects are obviously holding the `A` in the bass, but also the `D`, `E`, and `A` chords played above that are the *primary* triads of the key and include all tones of the key.

In terms of analyzing function, a pedal is usually either on the dominant or tonic scale degree, and it would simply be analyzed as `V` or `I`. All the chords and movement above a tonic wouldn't normally be analyzed. Although, the stuff above a tonic often moves by conventional voice leading and harmony.

Your progression is a little different, because it starts with a `D` chord...

[image]

I think it more or less does the same thing as the classical progression. It affirms `A` as tonic, but I think I would reduce and analyze it as...

[image]

That kind of progression - `I IV6/4 I` - using a *pedal* 6/4 chord is sometimes called a *tonic prolongation*. It's another way to affirm a tonic.

> Could the chord even be understood as a triple appoggiatura?

By my reckoning, yes, or maybe it should be called an *auxiliary* chord.

Have you ever heard the idea that the bass  provides the harmonic foundation, or "follow the bass" to understand the harmony? I think that takes us a long way with understanding this question. In these progressions the `E/A` is not *functioning* as a dominant, because the *bass is not moving off the tonic.* The bass is telling us `A` is the tonic.

Answer (score 6):

As described in the [previous answer linked in the comment by Elements in Space](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104163/what-does-the-chord-notation-x-y-slash-chord-mean/104164#104164):

**E/A** means to play the **E** chord with an **A** in the bass.

That answer gives several reasons why this notation might be used.  In the case of your excerpt, it's most likely a [pedal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_point), "a sustained tone, typically in the bass, during which at least one foreign (i.e. dissonant) harmony is sounded in the other parts".  (The G♯ of the E major chord is dissonant with the A.)

Comment: The OP used the slash chord notation above _staff_ notation. It seems like they understand what it means to play.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis The linked post also discusses contextual meaning.

Comment: Yes, but in a broad attempt to cover everything way, instead of responding directly to this OP's questions.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis but this answer does address this OP's question with its pedal point speculation.  And it certainly looks like a pedal point to me.

Answer (score 3):

As well as being a *pedal point* - as previously pointed out, since it goes on throughout, it could also be regarded as an *ostinato*. The pedal point is a single note that keeps getting repeated, regardless of chord - or even whether it belongs to the prevalent chord, whereas an ostinato is a repeated pattern - here a rhythmic pattern on a single note A. So I suppose it could even be called a *pedal point ostinato*!

Comment: Yes, and, btw, "ostinato" literally means "obstinate" :)

Answer (score 0):

This example is a bit complicated—I suspect it's a moment of modulation from another key, like maybe D major. At first I looked at the excerpt and thought, "A major?! Then why does it start with a D chord? It feels like it's in D!" Then I noticed the staff continuing to the left; this is a change of key signature and time signature. Perhaps the preceding section *was* in D.

If that were the case, then an E chord is easy to explain; it is in fact the dominant of A, and helps tonicize the new key. So we ask "why not have an E in the bass? Or any chordal tone that's a member of an E chord, rather than an A?" This ventures into "because, that's why" territory, but one speculation could be: Maybe (despite the change in key signature) we're not going to spend much time in A major. Maybe we want to keep a sense of A as the the dominant of D. Since the pitch A is a common member of both the D and A chords, sustaining it through the E helps keep a sense of "A as dominant" even through the brief V of A.

Comment: no, its all in A, nothing different happens before. Sorry, it is only an excerpt

Answer (score 0):

What it definitely ISN'T is a series of complicatedly-named A chords.   It's a D triad with A in the bass, then an E triad with A in the bass.  As the A bass persists for (at least) a few bars, we can call it a 'pedal note'.   Probably, ii this case, a 'Tonic Pedal'.   A very common harmonic device.

A series of chords over a 'Dominant Pedal' is possibly even more common.